# NUinit CollectionAssert not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, nunit

I have a view model class as follows:

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
        // Other properties......

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SecurityQuestions { get; set; }
    }
```

In my controller I have the following code:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel {SecurityQuestions = GetSecurityQuestions()};

    return View(viewModel);
}

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSecurityQuestions()
{
    return new SelectList(_securityQuestionService.GetAll(),
                          "SecurityQuestionID",
                          "Question");
}
```

I have written a unit test to test the Index action method:

```
  [Test]
    public void Can_Load_View_With_Security_Questions()
    {
        var result = _controller.Index();
        var questions = _controller.GetSecurityQuestions();
        var viewModel = result.ViewData.Model as MyViewModel;

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(questions, viewModel.SecurityQuestions);
    }
```

I was expecting this test to pass without any problems. But I am getting the below error:

```
Expected: <System.Web.Mvc.SelectList>
 But was: <System.Web.Mvc.SelectList>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What type does `_securityQuestionService.GetAll()` return?

Comment: It returns IEnumerable<SecurityQuestion>

Answer (score 0):

> I was expecting this test to pass without any problems

Why would you be expecting such a thing? The problem might come from the fact that you are calling the `_securityQuestionService.GetAll()` method twice. The first time inside the controller action and the second time inside your unit test which could different instances. Also the [`SelectList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.aspx) type doesn't override the Equals method so what you are experiencing is normal behavior.